# How to make an android TextView not to separate by symbol when the length is larger then the view width?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to show the user email address on a dialog.
In most cases, the dialog width is enough to show it.
(In my case, the textview width can put 20 chars per line.)
like: aabbccdd@gmail.com

But there are some problems with this kind of email address: aabbccdd.eeffgghh+0123456789@gmail.com

It may looks like this on the machine:

```
    aabbccdd.eeffgghh
    +0123456789
    @gmail.com
```

What I want is:

```
    aabbccdd.eeffgghh+01
    23456789@gmail.com
```

Is there any way can make it? 
Thanks.

Comment: try custom dialog box...

Comment: I'm already using custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I give up!

I use the String.length() & two TextView to handle it.